# Find all elements with width larger than xxx and output them to console

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am designing a web page in Joomla! and I run into a problem where I have an element I can't see that causes the page to scroll horizontally.

I'm completely useless with js and jQuery so can anyone help me with a script that will output to console all elements that have width larger than a specific value or larger than the browser window ? Or that can find in some other way which element causes the browser scroll horizontally ?

I would prefer a one line console script but a .js file will do also.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look in your browser's developer console. For example, Firefox can display you a nice 3D view!

If you really want to enumerate all elements whose width are greater than *x* in JavaScript, use this:

```
$("*").each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > 100) {
        console.log(this.tagName + "#" + this.id);
    }
});
```

Use `document.body.clientWidth` for *x* if you want to compare against the body's visible width.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Unfortunatly the page has so many elements due to a complex template that going through them with firebug isn't very productive. If I paste your script in the console I get 'TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of null'. I imagine I have to put it in a js file and call it from the page to run it properly ?

Comment: Did you include jQuery?

Comment: @Gatos If I insert my script in the Chrome dev console while being on StackOverflow.com, it works perfectly. I don't know how other browsers behave. Putting it in a JS file and running it after jQuery was embedded should definitely work.

Comment: Ah I had to replace $ with jQuery (cause of Joomla! i think) but now it runs. Thank you !

Comment: @Gatos Yeah, as far as I remember, Joomla uses MooTools which would conflict with jQuery if one doesn't use `jQuery = $.noConflict()` or the like ;)

Comment: Hmmm it seems like the script is giving me back every element ... all 263 of them :P if I run it here (on this page) it gives me back 851 elements ...

Comment: @Gatos With the code above, I get exactly 319 elements on StackOverflow (on this specific question page). You can freely adjust the width.

Answer (score 5):

To get window width simply use:

```
$(window).width()
```

So to use ComFreek's example, to loop through elements wider than your window width you would write is like this:

```
$("*").each(function() {
    if ($(this).width() > $(window).width()) {
        console.log(this.tagName + "#" + this.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

JS Code to find elements larger than window width, use in browser console:

```
var maxWidth = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
[].forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('*'),
  function(el) {
    if (el.offsetWidth > maxWidth) {
      console.log(el);
    }
  }
);
```

if still this give you haddache, use a bit of extreme css:

```
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What helped for me was running

```javascript
$("body *").each(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});
```

on the console. This helped me identifying elements that caused the document width to grow beyond the window width. In my case we had elements moving in from the outside of the document (hello fancy websites). This said, there wasn't a single element that was wider than the window width. They where simply positioned outside the ordinary bounds.

Since I was already using `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`, I ended up adding this CSS:

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used

`var outOfScreen = $('*').filter(function(){if($(this).width()>$(window).width())return true})`

so then I could inspect the whole collection by accessing the `outOfScreen` var.

Answer (score -1):

You not need a script. Open the page with Chrome, press F12 and in elements tab select each element, and you can see a each element in page with other color and  width.